# An always expanded MvxExpandableListView

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm trying to develop a version of the MvxExpandableListView that would always be expanded.

The code that I wrote seems to work, but I'm pretty sure I don't do things the right way. I tried to find some info about Android Widgets lifecycle, but found only info about Activity lifecycle.

More specifically, where should the ExpandAll() method be called ?
I've tried several places and ended by putting it into the OnDraw() handler.

To prevent collapsing, I called the ExpandGroup() method in the GroupCollapse Handler. hmm not sure it's the right way to do it either.

So, here is the code :

```
public class MvxExpandedListView : MvxExpandableListView
{
    private bool _allExpanded = false;

    private void ExpandAll()
    {
        var nbGroups = ThisAdapter.GroupCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < nbGroups; i++)
        {
            ExpandGroup(i);
        }
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        GroupCollapse += MvxExpandableListView_GroupCollapse;
        SetSelector(Android.Resource.Color.Transparent);
        CacheColorHint = Color.Transparent;
        SetGroupIndicator(null);
    }

    public MvxExpandedListView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
        : base(context, attrs)
    {
        Init();
    }

    public MvxExpandedListView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, MvxExpandableListAdapter adapter)
        : base(context, attrs, adapter)
    {
        Init();
    }

    protected MvxExpandedListView(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer)
        : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
        Init();
    }


    void MvxExpandableListView_GroupCollapse(object sender, ExpandableListView.GroupCollapseEventArgs e)
    {
        // There must be a better way...    
        this.ExpandGroup(e.GroupPosition);
    }

    protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        base.OnDraw(canvas);

        // Ugly !    
        if (!_allExpanded)
        {
            ExpandAll();
            _allExpanded = true;
        }

    }

    public override bool CollapseGroup(int groupPosition)
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance for your help,
Kindanam